# r for data science exercise 5.6.7 Q4

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working through r4ds by Hadley. I would like to know why the solution I have found requires mutate in the code. Is it possible to just use summarise? I thought they were interchangeable?

Q4: Look at the number of cancelled ﬂights per day. Is there a pattern? Is the proportion of cancelled ﬂights related to the average delay?

```
cancelled_delayed <- 
  flights %>%
  mutate(cancelled = (is.na(arr_delay) | is.na(dep_delay))) %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  summarise(prop_cancelled = mean(cancelled),
        avg_dep_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(cancelled_delayed, aes(x = avg_dep_delay, prop_cancelled)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could skip mutate and do the same thing in the summarise:

```
library(dplyr)
cancelled_delayed <- 
  flights %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  summarise(prop_cancelled = mean(is.na(arr_delay) | is.na(dep_delay)),
            avg_dep_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
```

But mutate and summarise are not at all interchangeable.

`mutate` is used to add oder update one or more columns in the existing table while keeping the general structure (number of rows) the same as it was. `summarise`, on the other hand, reduces the number of rows to 1 row per group, i.e. in your example 1 row per year-month-day combination.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance and explanation. That is much clearer to me now.